# Market makers outside of exchanges

Tags: stock-market, efficient-markets, exchange

I found this picture on SEC of how brokers will handle their customer's orders.[image]

Why are there market maker out side of exchange? Isn’t it dealers or wholesalers that’s not approved by exchanges as a market maker but want to profit from spread, and isn’t that the reason that they pay brokers for the order flow? (What’s called payment for order flow)

Comment: Best to ask in quant.stackechange. However, I think [investor.gov](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/how-stock-markets-work/executing-order), section "Your Broker Has Options for Executing Your Trade" should explain this nicely.  There are also OTC market makers (even for exchange traded stocks).

Comment: Thanks, I’ve asked this on quant but haven’t got an answer… aren’t otc market maker dealers or wholesalers as I said above?

Comment: And also Market makers on exchanges wouldn’t pay brokers for the order flow(payment for order flow) right? If any isn’t it exchanges that pay for the order flow? And I think OTC market makers(or dealers or wholesalers) are the ones that do pay brokers for the order flow, is it right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is [crossposted](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69960/market-makers-out-side-of-exchanges) and it does seem to be a better fit on Quant. Let's hope it gets a nice answer there.

Comment: Thanks, but I just wanted to know if my definition was right or not and that’s it…